# Do the house furniture bonuses of the same category stack?

Tags: the-trail

In "The Trail" there are several furniture that gives the same kind of bonuses.

Beds for example, reduce stamina consumption. But there are several beds.

Do I benefit only from the best bed installed at the house, or do all the beds bonuses add up?

Same for all the other furniture. Is it advantageous to have all of them or just the best one?

Answer (score -1):

I have observed the following whilst play-testing the game.

The gate seems to have the highest possible % bonus but at the moment even that bonus is hardly noticeable due to the bonuses being so small.
Due to the many parameters and their minor effects it is hard to judge if furniture bonuses stack.
Perhaps it will be more noticeable in future updates.

Comment: You should really break up this sentence. I attempted to edit it, but I lost track of what you were trying to say and gave up.